# PostgresSQL \d command tells about not existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I type `\l` into psql I got

```
                                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1251 | English_United States.1251 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1251 | English_United States.1251 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1251 | English_United States.1251 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

So here I have 1 database names postgres, but if I type `\d` I got

```
        List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner
--------+------+-------+----------
 public | db1  | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

In pgAdmin I can see 1 database named "postgres", so why `\d` tells me about db1 database? (I created it earlier and dropped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the psql help:

```
Informational
  (options: S = show system objects, + = additional detail)
  \d[S+]                 list tables, views, and sequences
```

And as your output shows, `db1` is a *table*, not a *database*...

`DROP TABLE db1;` will get rid of it.